# How is it possible to feed the output signal back to input using a TRRS connector

Tags: audio, analog, connector, speakers, microphone

I want to be able to "play" the output signal back to the device (in my case an XPERIA X10 which i think uses a standard TRRS plug) so that everything that is output by the device comes back to it. Would it be possible to simply loop [this](http://www.kvconnection.com/product-p/km-iphone-xtrs15.htm) cable?

Apologies for my ignorance - i really have no clue about even simplest electronics.

--oleg

Comment: @DaveMechGuru Yes its on that page but they call it TRRS i think if it has both mic and speaker connectors [pic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3.5mm.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But, I would get something cheaper.

Search for TRRS splitters. It splits a TRRS connector to a mic and a headphone connector.

Like this one:
[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Headset-Buddy-Smartphone-Computer-Blackberry/dp/B002SK66OY/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SK66OY)

That said, here are at least two issues I can think of:

1. Headphone output levels are typically higher than what a mic input expects. To start off, I would test on a device that is not your most expensive device. You should also start off with a low volume and work up from there. You can also avoid clipping by attenuating the signal before you loop it back in.
2. What happens to the signal depends on how an app is using the mic input. Of course this is in your control if you are writing the app. But something to think about.